# How to play swf file in android webview

Tags: android, webview, flash

Is android webview support swf files?
if yes then
How to play swf file in android webview from assets folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: already asked many times ... no longer possible

Comment: thanks for reply.
any third party library  available for this?

Comment: what for ? migration from flash to adobe air should be easy .... or you buy rights to swf without source?

Answer (score 0):

> Is android webview support swf files?

No. Android itself never did, and Adobe discontinued the Flash Player for Android some years ago.

Comment: Thanks You.
any lib available to play swf file or any alternative way to play swf?

Comment: @PrVN: I am not aware of any.